# How to set a vertical scroll bar of a smaller DIV to align with the right side of a larger DIV?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I  have 2 DIVs, the first one is 80% width of the screen.
The 2nd DIV is under the first one, I embedded another page xxx.html into it with AJAX onload function.It's width is 500px, how can I set a vertical scroll bar aligned with the right side of the first DIV? (the 2nd DIV's width is smaller than the 1st one.)

Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example image?

Answer (score 0):

I would put both divs to a container and float them to the right side.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1" style="width:80%; float:right"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="width:500px; float:right; clear:right"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4EGq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

if I am getting you right, you need to put the second div's content (iframe?) into another div, which is 80% width fixed. The content will be vertically scrollable if you set the height, too.